# sprintf giving out the wrong numbers Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

trying to add the float to the link below.

```
float val1 = 51.48

sprintf(buffer, "/xxx/xxx.php?load=%d", val1);
```

when I print val1 it show as 51.48 but when i use sprintf and then print the buffer it show -6501 i dont understand what is going on.

Comment: `%d` is for `int`s.

Comment: Check out this library: https://github.com/Lauszus/Serialf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use %f instead of %d in sprintf. %d is for printing integer so its truncating the digits after decimal point.

```
float val1 = 51.48

sprintf(buffer, "/xxx/xxx.php?load=%f", val1);
```

Comment: When i use %f it returns nothing.

Comment: you can devide the val1 in two ints. int1=val1 int2=(val1-int1)*100 then print "%d.%d" like this. This could be a solution.

Comment: So how can i split the float into 2 int|

Comment: `float val1 = 51.48;
int i1,i2;
i1 = (int)val1;
i2 = (val1 - i1)*100;
printf("%d.%d", i1, i2);
 `
if you want more precision you can multiply using 1,000 or 10,000 instead of 100.

Comment: By default, arduino ide does not support %f, to save memory. You can modiffy this compiler behavior, but avoiding usage of %f format is often better for a tiny target.

Comment: > "thanks worked great". ? sure ?  If you use `float val1=51.08;` you will notice that you should rather use `printf("%d.%02d", i1, i2);`